# Always Getting Null Values when calling the function GetAllUsers() while making Authentication controller in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication

I'm always getting NULL when calling the function `GetAllUsers()`. I'm trying to write an authentication controller in ASP.NET MVC.

This is the `AuthController`:

```
public class AuthController : Controller
{
     private readonly DbContext db = new DbContext();

     // GET: Auth
     public ActionResult Login()
     {
         return View();
     }

     [HttpPost]
     [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
     public ActionResult Login(User user)
     {
         if (ModelState.IsValid)
         {
             DomainUsers users = new DomainUsers();

             if (users.GetAllUsers().Find(x => x.Email == user.Email && x.Password == user.Password) != null)
             {
                 FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user.Email , false);
                 return RedirectToAction("Index", "Users");
             }
         }

         ModelState.AddModelError("", "invalid Email or Password");

         return View();
     }
}
```

This is the view:

```
@model WebApplication2.Models.User

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Login";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <!-- Section: Design Block -->
    <section class=" text-center text-lg-start">
        <style>
            .rounded-t-5 {
                border-top-left-radius: 0.5rem;
                border-top-right-radius: 0.5rem;
            }

            @@media (min-width: 992px) {
                .rounded-tr-lg-0 {
                    border-top-right-radius: 0;
                }

                .rounded-bl-lg-5 {
                    border-bottom-left-radius: 0.5rem;
                }
            }
        </style>

        <div class="card mb-3">
            <div class="row g-0 d-flex align-items-center">
                <div class="col-lg-4 d-none d-lg-flex">
                    <img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/new/ecommerce/vertical/004.jpg" alt="Trendy Pants and Shoes"
                         class="w-100 rounded-t-5 rounded-tr-lg-0 rounded-bl-lg-5" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-8">
                    <div class="card-body py-5 px-md-5">

                        <form>
                            <!-- Email input -->
                            <div class="form-outline mb-4">
                                <input type="email" id="form2Example1" class="form-control" />
                                <label class="form-label" for="form2Example1">Email address</label>
                            </div>

                            <!-- Password input -->
                            <div class="form-outline mb-4">
                                <input type="password" id="form2Example2" class="form-control" />
                                <label class="form-label" for="form2Example2">Password</label>
                            </div>

                            <!-- 2 column grid layout for inline styling -->
                            <div class="row mb-4">
                                <div class="col d-flex justify-content-center">
                                    <!-- Checkbox -->
                                    <div class="form-check">
                                        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="form2Example31" checked />
                                        <label class="form-check-label" for="form2Example31"> Remember me </label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col">
                                    <!-- Simple link -->
                                    <a href="#!">Forgot password?</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <!-- Submit button -->
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block mb-4">Sign in</button>

                        </form>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
}
<!-- Section: Design Block -->
```

I tried this also, but it also returns `NULL` always:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(UserModel model)
{
    using (DBContext context = new DBContext())
    {
        bool IsValidUser = context.Users.Any(user => user.UserName.ToLower() ==
             model.UserName.ToLower() && user.UserPassword == model.UserPassword);

        if (IsValidUser)
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, false);
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Employees");
        }

        ModelState.AddModelError("", "invalid Username or Password");

        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not too familiar with EntityFramework, however you should run the application and debug at the point where isValidUser is getting initialized. Look at the values that are being passed, it will give an idea why false is being returned.

Comment: `x.Password == user.Password` <-- [Please don't do this](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/120540/why-shouldnt-i-store-passwords-in-plaintext)s

Answer (score 1):

First of all, check if your database has the desired data.

second you can simplify the condition like

```
var users = GetAllUsers().ToList();

if (users.where(x => x.Email == user.Email && x.Password == user.Password) != null)
         {
             FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user.Email , false);
             return RedirectToAction("Index", "Users");
         }
```

I hope this will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check the existing of this user in the domain, try a special method for this - **ValidateCredentials(user, password)** :

```
using (System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext pc = new(ContextType.Domain))
{
    // validate the credentials
    if (pc.ValidateCredentials(model.UserName, model.UserPassword))
    {
        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user.Email , false);
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Users");
    }
}
```